# wp_login Cannot modify header information

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to login user by this code.

```
$user_id = '1';
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
if( $user ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
```

but getting this error.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   E:\WebDev\ope-time\wp_development\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:124)
>   in E:\WebDev\ope-time\wp_development\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line
>   925

Comment: look up the two lines mention in the error message. Probably you have output something before you are allowed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code at the [init-action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) (at this time no headers have been sended yet)

Comment: let me check. Thanks